# What is the purpose of the ID Token if I can get the user info from the userinfo endpoint?

Tags: oidc

I am trying to understand OIDC and i dont see the purpose of the ID token if with just the access token, i can make a request to the userinfo endpoint and get the user info. What then is the purpose of the ID token?

In addition, what links an access token to a specific ID token? Are they linked at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I understood it, the `id_token` is just a standardized way to signal the client application that the user has been **authenticated**. It might also save you some round-trip depending on the additional info that is contained in the `id_token`.

Just in case you haven't seen it yet. There is a  great explainer video called [OAuth 2.0 and OpenID Connect in Plain English](https://youtu.be/996OiexHze0?t=2894) that I found very helpful.

Comment: Actually according to OAuth protocol, if you got access token - it means Authorization Server authenticated the Resource Owner
https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-4.1

" (B)  The authorization server authenticates the resource owner (via
        the user-agent) and establishes whether the resource owner
        grants or denies the client's access request"